# Parsing IMAP + mailparser return object into a JSON

Tags: json, node.js, imap, email-parsing

I am using node's IMAP & Mailparser modules for this.

My mailbox reader function has this line that parses the header:

```
var parsed_header = inspect(Imap.parseHeader(buffer));
```

This will then return:

```
{ from: [ 'user <user@mail.com>' ],
subject: [ 'Test' ] }
```

I want to be able to parse this into a JSON using JSON.parse, but because there is no quotes around the keys + the keys are all in lists, could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the same problem with two regex replacements:

```
var header = inspect(Imap.parseHeader(buffer)).replace(/'/g,'"').replace(/([a-z]+)(: ?[\[\n])/g, '"$1"$2');
var headerObj = JSON.parse(header);
```

The first one replaces single quotes with double quotes, the second adds quotes around the field names.

Answer (score 1):

Just do `var parsed_header = Imap.parseHeader(buffer)` and you will have an object. So for get the "from" field you can just use `parsed_header.from`